# how to compare two or more values in excel with values in li and report pass or fail in same excel using apache poi selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, excel, selenium, apache-poi

I need to import 2 or more values from excel and compare the value which i have in my li's , the code i have used is

```
FileInputStream input=new FileInputStream(new File("TestCase.xls"));    
HSSFWorkbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook(input);
HSSFSheet sheet=workbook.getSheet("KeywordFramework");
System.out.println("i am in"); 
int rowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
System.out.println(rowNum);
int colNum = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
System.out.println(colNum);
String data [][] = new String[rowNum][colNum];
for(int i =1 ; i< rowNum;i++)       
{
    System.out.println("1");
    HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
    for(int j = 0; j<= colNum;j++)          
    {
    System.out.println("2");
    HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
    String Cellvalue = cellToString(cell);
    System.out.println("cellvalue === "+Cellvalue);
    switch(j)
    {
   `case 1:
    case 2:
        ExpectedOP=Cellvalue;

        System.out.println("Expected output (value to be compared) = "+ExpectedOP);
        int LastRow = 1;
        List <WebElement> we =  driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='stepList']/li"));//Getting list of elements in steplist ul
        for(int i1=2;i1<=we.size();i1++)                
        {
        String sr [] =new String [10];
        sr [i1]=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='stepList']/li["+i1+"]")).getText().trim();//Getting required li text data (example : abc)

        for (String j1:sr)
            {
            if(j1 != null)
            {
            String [] parts = sr [i1].split("/");//Spliting to get the required data
            String parta = parts [0].trim();//Triming the whitespaces
            System.out.println("Step value = "+parta);

            if(ExpectedOP.equals(parta))//Comparing value in Excel with value got in excel
            {
                System.out.println("compare pass");
                String status="PASS";
                [Write into excel];
                break;
            }
             else
            {
                System.out.println("compare pass");
                String status="Fail";
                [Write into excel];
                break;
            }//Close else
            }//Close if j1 null
            }//Close for j1
            }//Close i1 for loop
            }//Close Switch(j)
            }}}//Close the rest`
```

The value of Excel is not getting incremented once i get the next value , i.e., say if the first value from excel was abc and abc is compared with the value in li1 which is abc and say pass , and for i1 for loop gets li2 value as xyz but still the cellvalue will be abc , i want the cell value to be xyz so that i can compare xyz value of cell with value in li2

Comment: do you comparing excel value with website value? or both values are in excel in diff. col?

Comment: I am comparing excel value with website value , but i need to get 2 values from excel so am using " case 1 : case 2 : " because li has 2 values which should be compared with those 2 values present in excel file

Comment: But why you are not doing 1 li with 1 cell comparison?

Comment: ya it should do 1 li with 1 cell and second li with second cell and say result pass/fail , if first one fails then it should not compare the second value , it should brake from the case and go to next control

Comment: ok so where you are getting issue? in comparison or in write to excel?

Comment: in both, When i am comparing li2 value i want cell 2 value , but i still have cell 1 value , and the result is not rewriting , In short "CellValue" should be cell2 value of excel when for i1 loop and for j1 loop is getting incremented even "CellValue" should change to value in cell2

Comment: String data [][] = new String[rowNum][colNum]; - Why you are using this? also 2 diff. loops? data can be written using single loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66396/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-user3724559).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below sample program to compare value from excel with site console output :

```
    //CALL FIREFOX DRIVER TO OPEN IT
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


    driver.get("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing");
    String title = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(title);

    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("D:\\sel.xls");

    int count=0;

    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(input);
    HSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet("sheet1");
    HSSFRow row = sh.getRow(count);
    String data = row.getCell(1).toString();
    System.out.println(data);


    FileOutputStream webdata = new FileOutputStream ("D:\\sel.xls");
    if(title.equals(data))

    {

        row.createCell(10).setCellValue("TRUE");
        wb.write(webdata);

    }
    else
    {

        row.createCell(11).setCellValue("FALSE");
        wb.write(webdata);

    }

    driver.close(); 
    wb.close();
    input.close();


}


}
```

Comment: Please consider including some information about your answer, rather than simply posting code. We try to provide not just 'fixes', but help people learn. You should explain what was wrong in the original code, what you did differently, and why your change(s) worked.